# Error when trying to update database in .NET Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

I am trying to update a database in .NET Core using the command

```
dotnet ef database update
```

but I am getting the following error

> Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14
> Login failed for user ''.

I can log in in my SQL Server with this User ID and password so I don´t think the problem is in my connection string

### Context

```
   public class CommanderContext : DbContext
    {
        public CommanderContext(DbContextOptions<CommanderContext> opt) : base(opt)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Command> Commands { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### appsettings.cs

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CommanderConnection": "Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=CommanderDB,User ID=CommanderApi;Password=*****;"
  }
}
```

### Startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddDbContext<CommanderContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CommanderConnection")));
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddScoped<ICommanderRepo, MockCommanderRepo>();


        }
```

I also leave a print of my SQL Server

[image]

Comment: Is this a new or an existing database? Are remote connections allowed? Did this user ID/password work when you first scaffolded the database, if you're using Code-First approach?

Comment: The SSMS screenshot is not helpful at all, as it only shows existence of the SQL Login, not the rights

Comment: The clue is in the error message `Login failed for user` and your statement "I don´t think the problem is in my connection string" - the update statement may not be seeing the connection string or the string has errors.

Comment: @CoolBots it is a new database

Comment: @PeterSmith so my problem is in Startup.cs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you've got a comma in the connection string just before User Id.

This needs to be a semicolon:

```
 "CommanderConnection": "Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=CommanderDB;User ID=CommanderApi;Password=*****;"
```